# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/OpenUDID/OpenUDID_manager$ValueComparator;

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm developing for Android in Eclipse for not a long time ago and recently I encountered a problem. I created a library in which i use two additional jar libraries: `appbooster.jar` and `adcolony.jar`. After i added the created library to the main application, on launching it says:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(22887):
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com.appsfire.appbooster.jar.af_NotificationsManager
E/AndroidRuntime(22887):at com.testlib.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
...
```

I added the appbooster.jar and adcolony.jar to the main application too (Properties-->Java Build Path-->Libraries-->Add External JARs). The same result:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(26403): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(26403): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com.appsfire.appbooster.jar.af_NotificationsManager
E/AndroidRuntime(26403):at com.testlib.LibClass.initiateAppBooster(LibClass.java:9)
```

Then i went to (Properties-->Java Build Path-->Order and Export) from main application and checked those 2 jar files (appbooster and adcolony). Now it says:

```
[2013-09-16 16:54:24 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/OpenUDID/OpenUDID_manager$ValueComparator;
[2013-09-16 16:54:24 - TestApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/OpenUDID/OpenUDID_manager$ValueComparator;
```

Can anybody please help me. I've been working on this error for quite a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both appbooster.jar and adcolony.jar bundle the OpenUDID libraries.  Delete those files from one of the libraries, e.g.:

```
zip adcolony.jar -d org/OpenUDID/*
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, you saved me. I deleted OpenUDID from adcolony.jar as you said and it worked. Now both libraries are set in one project.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put the JAR libraries? They should be under your `libs` folder within your Android application. This seems the most likely possibility because your Android Java code cannot read those classes that are in those JAR packages. So I would definitely check whether they are actually in the `libs` directory within your Android project.

Please see the following [article](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/jar-for-android/).

Comment: Thanks for the article, i did everything as it says in there but it's no use. The result is the same. Could it be that this two jar files are incompatible with each other? The project works fine if i use only one of those jars. (Of course in this case i can not use the classes of the other one).

Comment: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/OpenUDID/OpenUDID_manager$ValueComparator;
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/OpenUDID/OpenUDID_manager$ValueComparator;

Answer (score 0):

Under your libs folder, check to see if there are more than one of the same .jar file i.e `gson-1.0` and `gson-1.0(1)`. Delete the latter if there is.

Comment: There are no jar files with same names.

Comment: Similar thing happened to me once and that was the problem, sorry!